linux netlink netdev (family) protocol: how to get queue information for netdevs/interfaces in operstate down?
The Linux kernel provides a generic NETLINK "netdev" (family) protocol for querying information about NIC RX and TX queue configuration, and NAPI instance details, such as queue-specific IRQs. The benefit of this "netdev" protocol is that it avoids problems with /sys/class/net which gets frozen to a particular network namespace and mount time. Also this API provides information not available through the ethtool ioctls or the ethtool NETLINK protocol, such as the correct queue IDs (indices).
I'm using the NETDEV_CMD_QUEUE_GET command; however, this does not return any information about network interfaces that are in operstate down (neither up nor unknown). Trying to "GET" queue information for a specific NETDEV_A_QUEUE_IFINDEX succeeds but yields no queue information, as netdev_nl_queue_dump_one skips over anything that hasn't IFF_UP.
Is there a(nother) way to still get the queue information (and not being sysfs or ethtool) for a network interface that isn't (yet) up or what am I doing wrong here? Why is netdev_nl_queue_dump_one skipping over netdevs that are down?
